# Process PHP and print to string

Tags: php, html

I've got a PHP page (content.php), containing plain HTML and content delivered by PHP variables

```
<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
          <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
     </body>
</html>
```

Then there is another PHP page, where I need the contents of content.php in a String, but already processed by the PHP parser. I already tried the file_get_contents() function, but this gives the raw output (PHP not processed). What I'm looking for, is this:

`$var contents = somefunction('contents.php')` with content:

```
<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
          <h1>Title</h1>
     </body>
</html>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ob_start();
include ('contents.php');
$html = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm! However, the function ob_end() does not exist, and I used ob_end_flush()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`include`](http://php.net/include)? Alternatively, if you need to get it from "outside" (like if you loaded it in your browser) use `file_get_contents` with the full `http://example.com/filename.php` URL.

Answer (score 0):

either i am missing something badly here or else instead of using a function, in your second page why not just directly assign the contents to a string like this:

```
$my_String = "<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
          <h1>". $title ."</h1>
     </body>
</html>";
```